# Justify buttons with Bootstrap v4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap v4 drops the `.btn-group-justified` class, see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17631

How to justify the button for:

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Left</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Middle</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Right</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Indeed the nav-justify class is missing. You can add it yourself based on TB3's code for now:

### SCSS code

```
// Justified button groups
// ----------------------

.btn-group-justified {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  .btn,
  .btn-group {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    .btn {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
      left: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

### compiled CSS code

```
.btn-group-justified {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate; }
  .btn-group-justified .btn,
  .btn-group-justified .btn-group {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%; }
    .btn-group-justified .btn .btn,
    .btn-group-justified .btn-group .btn {
      width: 100%; }
    .btn-group-justified .btn .dropdown-menu,
    .btn-group-justified .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
      left: auto; }
```

### HTML

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Left</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Middle</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Right</a>
 </div>
```

The above HTML code now will look like that shown in the figure beneath:

[image]

#### Handling borders

- Due to the specific HTML and CSS used to justify buttons (namely `display: table-cell`), the borders between them are doubled. In regular button groups, `margin-left: -1px` is used to stack the borders instead of removing them. However, `margin` doesn't work with `display: table-cell`. As a result, depending on your customizations to Bootstrap, you may wish to remove or re-color the borders.

#### Links acting as buttons

- If the `<a>` elements are used to act as buttons – triggering in-page functionality, rather than navigating to another document or section within the current page – they should also be given an appropriate `role="button"`.

### Dropdowns

Use the following HTML code for dropdown buttons:

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group with nested dropdown">
   <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Left</a>
   <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Middle</a>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The justified button group with dropdown button should look like that shown in the figure below:

[image]

### With `<button>` elements

- To use justified button groups with `<button>` elements, **you must wrap each button in a button group**. Most browsers don't properly apply our CSS for justification to `<button>` elements, but since we support button dropdowns, we can work around that.

#### HTML

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The above HTML code used to justified button groups with `<button>` elements should look like that shown in the figure beneath:

[image]

Comment: why set the width of the btn to 1% within the btn-group? Is this intended?

Answer (score 76):

For anyone finding this after Bootstrap 4 Beta was released...

```html
<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group">
   <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">Previous</a>
   <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for... I think I must learn more about flex styles in Bootstrap 4

Comment: Should be first answer, no need for custom CSS, less hacky. Well done!

Comment: simple,sharp and clean. great!

Answer (score 24):

Building on [Bass Jobsen's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34450587/6694848), here is the same functionality using flexbox instead of `display: table;`

## SCSS code

```
// Justified button groups
// ----------------------

.btn-group-justified {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  .btn,
  .btn-group {
    flex: 1;
    .btn {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
      left: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="Justified button group">
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Left</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Middle</a>
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Right</a>
 </div>
```

Please refer to [Bass Jobsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34450587/6694848) for more details on usage with dropdowns, HTML Links and more.

Comment: Excellent, it also avoids the double-border issue

Comment: Suggestion: add `& + & {margin-top: $btn-block-spacing-y;}` to space out stacked justified button groups

Answer (score 0):

When using with `class="dropdown-menu"` with Bootstrap V4.0, based on Chris Baswell' solution above and Bootstrap Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/#nesting

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
    <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle-no-carret w-100" title="MANAGE ENTRIES" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Drop Down
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">Previous</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```