# Justified .btn-group with Bootstrap v4-alpha-5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, buttongroup

The question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450586/justify-buttons-with-bootstrap-v4) addresses justified button group in < alpha-3. It doesn't work in alpha-5 (and I think in alpha-4 also).

From what I gather from the issues list, it has been removed and won't be back.

I'm using SCSS and and potentially flexbox if this provides a better solution.

I would like to use the [toggle-state radio-buttons](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Is anyone able to provide a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Justify buttons with Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450586/justify-buttons-with-bootstrap-v4)

Comment: Nope. Read the question. I mention in the first line that question you are referring to is using alpha 3, whereas at the time I was using alpha 5. Before you jump to conclusions, read the question.

Comment: I was under the impression that the question was about Bootstrap 4 in general, the latest answer to it (which made it into the official docs BTW) is about the first beta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group">
   <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">Previous</a>
   <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary w-100">Next</a>
</div>
```

Read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#button-group

Comment: Thank you. I know that they have recently added this to the docs as it wasn't there previously.

Comment: Recently I myself have been looking for :)

Comment: This works with `a`'s and `button`s, I can't get it to work with toggles :s (edit: It DOES work (mind the `w-100` class) .. But it does brake the toggle, now they show the inputs)

Answer (score -1):

You can alway add custom css to your code, if its missing

```
.btn-group-justified {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.btn-group-justified .btn,
.btn-group-justified .btn-group {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
}
.btn-group-justified .btn .btn,
.btn-group-justified .btn-group .btn {
    width: 100%;
}
.btn-group-justified .btn .dropdown-menu,
.btn-group-justified .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
}
```

Comment: See SCSS and more details in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450586/justify-buttons-with-bootstrap-v4/39119031#39119031) post.

Comment: Hi @Max the link you posted is the same one that I referenced in my question! Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Whoops, overlooked that! Philip Stanislaus' answer there worked for me on alpha-6 with flexbox on. I did have to wrap each button in an extra button group though.